# Is there specific name bunk beds that are stable in a room?

Tags: vocabulary

As far as I know "bunk beds" are beds that a bed stacks on another one.

Is there a specific name for bunk beds that are the built-in type like this?

[image]

Image from http://trica-hostel.com/jp/hostel.html#dormitory

Comment: One might call it their little cubbyhole, though they may be stretching the mean of the term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of two-storey beds are bunks, whether built-in or not.